# Download a 'data:' image/file using puppeteer and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to download an image using node.js and puppeteer but I'm running into some issues. I'm using a webscraper to gather the links of the images from the site and then using the https/http package to download the image.

This works for the images using http and https sources but some images have links that look like this (the whole link is very long so I cut the rest):

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAw8AAADGCAYAAACU07w3AAAZuUlEQVR4Ae3df4yU930n8Pcslu1I1PU17okdO1cLrTD+g8rNcvRyti6247K5NG5S5HOl5hA2uZ7du6RJEGYPTFy1Nv4RUJy0cWVkeQ9ErqqriHNrR8niZuVIbntBS886rBZWCGHVsNEFRQ5BloPCzGn2B+yzZMLyaP........

I'm not sure how to handle these links or how to download the image. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first decode the url from base64 using node.js `Buffer`.

```js
// the content type image/png has to be removed first
const data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAw8AAADGCAYAAACU07w3AAAZuUlEQVR4Ae3df4yU930n8Pcslu1I1PU17okdO1cLrTD+g8rNcvRyti6247K5NG5S5HOl5hA2uZ7du6RJEGYPTFy1Nv4RUJy0cWVkeQ9ErqqriHNrR8niZuVIbntBS886rBZWCGHVsNEFRQ5BloPCzGn2B+yzZMLyaP';
const buffer = new Buffer(data);
const base64data = buff.toString('base64');

// after this you will get the url string and continue to fetch the image
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the base64 encoded images (mostly used for icons and small images).

you can ignore it.

```js
 if(url.startsWith('data:')){
   //base 64 image
 } else{
   // an image url
 }
```

if you really want to mess with base64 I can give you a workaround.

```js
import { parseDataURI } from 'dauria';
import mimeTypes from 'mime-types';

const fileContent = parseDataURI(file);
 // you probably need an extension for that image.
let ext = mimeTypes.extension(fileContent.MIME) || 'bin';

fs.writeFile("a random file"+"."+ext, fileContent.buffer, function (err) {
    console.log(err); // writes out file without error, but it's not a valid image
});
```